# what is the right ldapsearch version for my linux red-hat machine

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I am little a confused about the following:

I want to install the binary **ldapsearch** tool on my Linux machine,
in order to use this tool to test LDAP connections with my Linux (Linux version 5.8 , i386 ) client.

I went, for example, to this link (where I see a lot of ldapsearch rpm’s) but I see no version for my Linux 5.8 i386

```
      http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ldapsearch&submit=Search+...
```

Can someone advise me what is the most suitable tool for my Linux machine and from where I need to download the ldapsearch tool?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

First what is your Linux Distribution ? If it's a Redhat based you can run the following command to determine your distribution name:

cat /etc/redhat-release

If it's a RedHat based system you should use "yum" which is the default package manager of RedHat based systems.

How to use yum : [Yum RedHat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-yum.html)

Usually the name of the RPM package that contain the ldapsearch binary is : openldap-clients

Regards, Edouard.

Answer (score -1):

For Redhat packages, you can always count on CentOS repos.

Check this link, if it works for you
http://vault.centos.org/5.8/os/i386/CentOS/openldap-clients-2.3.43-25.el5.i386.rpm

You can also add the repo for make the most of it by replacing this on redhat-release package:
http://vault.centos.org/5.8/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-5-8.el5.centos.i386.rpm